# git svn fetch - Session URL does not match expected session URL

Tags: git-svn

I try to execute git svn fetch on a ubuntu machine that host a svn server. (transfering svn repo to git) git svn response with the error:

```
Session URL does not match expected session URL: Repository moved permanently to 'http://localhost/svn/repo' at /usr/share/perl5/Git/SVN.pm line 148.
```

I am able to access the svn repository over the browser:

[image]

`svn co http://localhost/svn/repo/trunk` also works.

The config of my git repository look like:

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
    url = http://localhost/svn/repo
    fetch = trunk:refs/remotes/origin/trunk
    branches = branches/branchA/*:refs/remotes/branchA/*
```

Last year I do the exact same process without any issues. What should the error message tell to me?

**GIT_TRACE=1:**

```
07:30:19.957480 git.c:576               trace: exec: git-svn fetch
07:30:19.957508 run-command.c:646       trace: run_command: git-svn fetch
06:30:20.264901 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git rev-parse --git-dir
06:30:20.270689 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git rev-parse --show-cdup
06:30:20.280345 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git config --bool --get svn.useSvmProps
06:30:20.282850 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git config --get svn.ignorerefs
06:30:20.284977 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git config --bool --get svn.uselogauthor
06:30:20.289744 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git config --int --get svn.logwindowsize
06:30:20.296912 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git config --get svn.repackflags
06:30:20.302913 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git config --bool --get svn.parent
06:30:20.308843 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git config --bool --get svn.noMetadata
06:30:20.313303 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git config --get svn.authorsprog
06:30:20.315443 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git config --bool --get svn.fetchall
06:30:20.325453 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git config --get svn.configdir
06:30:20.327644 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git config --int --get svn.repack
06:30:20.336702 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git config --get svn.includepaths
06:30:20.339225 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git config --get svn.username
06:30:20.341358 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git config --bool --get svn.localtime
06:30:20.350228 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git config --bool --get svn.useSvnsyncProps
06:30:20.352446 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git config --bool --get svn.nocheckout
06:30:20.361053 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git config --get svn.authorsfile
06:30:20.365090 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git config --get svn.ignorepaths
06:30:20.367110 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git config --bool --get svn.followparent
06:30:20.376769 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git config --get svn.revision
06:30:20.378979 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git config --bool --get svn.addauthorfrom
06:30:20.384743 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git config --bool --get svn.noauthcache
06:30:20.389012 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git config --bool --get svn.quiet
06:30:20.391455 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git rev-parse --symbolic --all
06:30:20.444247 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git rev-parse --git-path svn
06:30:20.453089 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git config -l
06:30:20.465201 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git config -l
06:30:20.468112 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git config --bool svn.useSvmProps
06:30:20.474744 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git config -l
Session URL does not match expected session URL: Repository moved permanently to 'http://localhost/svn/repo' at /usr/share/perl5/Git/SVN.pm line 148.
```

Comment: Do you get any solution?

Comment: Yes, see my answer below. I had to use `url = file:///localhost/svn/repo` instead of `url = http://localhost/svn/repo`

Comment: Thank you for your response. I simply move away from the command and clone the svn using the SmartGit with graphical presentation and it is working well. All history sync properly to Git. It is creating a brunch named trunk rather from the master which is not a problem as we always work on specific branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find an old version of my virtual machine. The correct git config should looks like:

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
    url = file:///localhost/svn/repo  # <-  instead of http://
    fetch = trunk:refs/remotes/origin/trunk
    branches = branches/branchA/*:refs/remotes/branchA/*
```

Hope this prevent someday ppl wasting time...